# Scrapy shows the same result for a dynamic website

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

My problem with Scrapy is that every day when I run it for a certain project I get the same exact result although there are elements that change every day on the **scraped** website since it is not a static website.

These are some parts of the log I get whenever I run my spider:

```
2020-09-01 13:37:29 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Scrapy 1.6.0 started (bot: digikala)
2020-09-01 13:37:29 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Versions: lxml 4.5.2.0, libxml2 2.9.10, cssselect 1.1.0, parsel 1.5.2, w3lib 1.21.0, Twisted 20.3.0, Python 3.8.5 (default, Aug  5 2020, 09:44:06) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)], pyOpenSSL 19.1.0 (OpenSSL 1.1.1g  21 Apr 2020), cryptography 2.9.2, Platform Windows-10-10.0.19041-SP0
2020-09-01 13:37:29 [scrapy.crawler] INFO: Overridden settings: {'AUTOTHROTTLE_MAX_DELAY': 120, 'AUTOTHROTTLE_START_DELAY': 60, 'BOT_NAME': 'digikala', 'FEED_FORMAT': 'xml', 'FEED_URI': '99-06-11.xml', 'HTTPCACHE_ENABLED': True, 'NEWSPIDER_MODULE': 'digikala.spiders', 'ROBOTSTXT_OBEY': True, 'SPIDER_MODULES': ['digikala.spiders']}
2020-09-01 13:37:29 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] INFO: Telnet Password: ecded85f3ba24c1b
2020-09-01 13:37:29 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled extensions:
['scrapy.extensions.corestats.CoreStats',
 'scrapy.extensions.telnet.TelnetConsole',
 'scrapy.extensions.feedexport.FeedExporter',
 'scrapy.extensions.logstats.LogStats']
2020-09-01 13:37:29 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled downloader middlewares:
['scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.robotstxt.RobotsTxtMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpauth.HttpAuthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.downloadtimeout.DownloadTimeoutMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.defaultheaders.DefaultHeadersMiddleware',
 'digikala.middlewares.UserAgentRotatorMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry.RetryMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.MetaRefreshMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpcompression.HttpCompressionMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.RedirectMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.cookies.CookiesMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpproxy.HttpProxyMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.stats.DownloaderStats',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpcache.HttpCacheMiddleware']
2020-09-01 13:37:29 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled spider middlewares:
['scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror.HttpErrorMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.offsite.OffsiteMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.referer.RefererMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.urllength.UrlLengthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.depth.DepthMiddleware']
2020-09-01 13:37:29 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled item pipelines:
[]
2020-09-01 13:37:29 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened
2020-09-01 13:37:29 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2020-09-01 13:37:29 [scrapy.extensions.httpcache] DEBUG: Using filesystem cache storage in C:\Users\shima\projects\digikala\.scrapy\httpcache
2020-09-01 13:37:29 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] INFO: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6023
2020-09-01 13:37:29 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.digikala.com/robots.txt> (referer: None) ['cached']
2020-09-01 13:37:29 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.digikala.com/search/category-book/?type[0]=4844&promotion_types[0]=incredible_offer&promotion_types[1]=promotion&pageno=1&last_filter=promotion_types&last_value=incredible_offer&sortby=4> (referer: None) ['cached']
2020-09-01 13:37:29 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.digikala.com/search/category-book/?type[0]=4844&promotion_types[0]=incredible_offer&promotion_types[1]=promotion&pageno=1&last_filter=promotion_types&last_value=incredible_offer&sortby=4>
{'title': 'کتاب خودت را به فنا نده اثر گری جان بیشاپ', 'star': 4.4, 'discounted_percent': 30, 'discounted_price': 12600, 'original_price': 18000, 'discounted_amount': 5400, 'url': 'https://www.digikala.com/product/dkp-1050124/کتاب-خودت-را-به-فنا-نده-اثر-گری-جان-بیشاپ'}
2020-09-01 13:37:29 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.digikala.com/search/category-book/?type[0]=4844&promotion_types[0]=incredible_offer&promotion_types[1]=promotion&pageno=1&last_filter=promotion_types&last_value=incredible_offer&sortby=4>
{'title': 'کتاب تختخوابت را مرتب کن اثر ژنرال ویلیام اچ. مک ریون', 'star': 4.4, 'discounted_percent': 30, 'discounted_price': 10500, 'original_price': 15000, 'discounted_amount': 4500, 'url': 'https://www.digikala.com/product/dkp-392946/کتاب-تختخوابت-را-مرتب-کن-اثر-ژنرال-ویلیام-اچ-مک-ریون'}
 {'title': 'کتاب روش تعبیر رویا اثر زیگموند فروید', 'star': 4.6, 'discounted_percent': 15, 'discounted_price': 25500, 'original_price': 30000, 'discounted_amount': 4500, 'url': 'https://www.digikala.com/product/dkp-37908/کتاب-روش-تعبیر-رویا-اثر-زیگموند-فروید'}
2020-09-01 13:37:30 [scrapy.core.scraper] ERROR: Spider error processing <GET https://www.digikala.com/search/category-book/?type%5B0%5D=4844&promotion_types%5B0%5D=incredible_offer&promotion_types%5B1%5D=promotion&last_filter=promotion_types&last_value=incredible_offer&sortby=4&pageno=2> (referer: https://www.digikala.com/search/category-book/?type[0]=4844&promotion_types[0]=incredible_offer&promotion_types[1]=promotion&pageno=1&last_filter=promotion_types&last_value=incredible_offer&sortby=4)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\shima\anaconda3\envs\virtual_workspace\lib\site-packages\scrapy\utils\defer.py", line 102, in iter_errback
    yield next(it)
  File "C:\Users\shima\anaconda3\envs\virtual_workspace\lib\site-packages\scrapy\spidermiddlewares\offsite.py", line 29, in process_spider_output
    for x in result:
  File "C:\Users\shima\anaconda3\envs\virtual_workspace\lib\site-packages\scrapy\spidermiddlewares\referer.py", line 339, in <genexpr>
    return (_set_referer(r) for r in result or ())
  File "C:\Users\shima\anaconda3\envs\virtual_workspace\lib\site-packages\scrapy\spidermiddlewares\urllength.py", line 37, in <genexpr>
    return (r for r in result or () if _filter(r))
  File "C:\Users\shima\anaconda3\envs\virtual_workspace\lib\site-packages\scrapy\spidermiddlewares\depth.py", line 58, in <genexpr>
    return (r for r in result or () if _filter(r))
  File "C:\Users\shima\projects\digikala\digikala\spiders\promotions.py", line 22, in parse
    star= float(str(product.xpath(".//div[@class='c-product-box__engagement-rating']/text()").get()))
ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'None'
2020-09-01 13:37:30 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2020-09-01 13:37:30 [scrapy.extensions.feedexport] INFO: Stored xml feed (44 items) in: 99-06-11.xml
2020-09-01 13:37:30 [scrapy.statscollectors] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
{'downloader/request_bytes': 1593,
 'downloader/request_count': 3,
 'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 3,
 'downloader/response_bytes': 164205,
 'downloader/response_count': 3,
 'downloader/response_status_count/200': 3,
 'finish_reason': 'finished',
 'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2020, 9, 1, 9, 7, 30, 166863),
 'httpcache/hit': 3,
 'item_scraped_count': 44,
 'log_count/DEBUG': 48,
 'log_count/ERROR': 1,
 'log_count/INFO': 10,
 'request_depth_max': 1,
 'response_received_count': 3,
 'robotstxt/request_count': 1,
 'robotstxt/response_count': 1,
 'robotstxt/response_status_count/200': 1,
 'scheduler/dequeued': 2,
 'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 2,
 'scheduler/enqueued': 2,
 'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 2,
 'spider_exceptions/ValueError': 1,
 'start_time': datetime.datetime(2020, 9, 1, 9, 7, 29, 622333)}
2020-09-01 13:37:30 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
```

This is my middlewares.py where I defined auto-rotating user-agent:

```
from scrapy import signals
from scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.useragent import UserAgentMiddleware
import random, logging


class UserAgentRotatorMiddleware(UserAgentMiddleware):
    user_agent_list=[
        'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome',
        'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko'
    ]
    def __init__(self, user_agent=''):
        self.user_agent= user_agent
    def process_request(self, request, spider):
        try:
            self.user_agent= random.choice(self.user_agent_list)
            request.headers.setdefault('User-Agent', self.user_agent)
        except IndexError:
            logging.error("Couldn't fetch the user agent")
```

These are my settings.py codes that I commented out:

```
BOT_NAME = 'digikala'

SPIDER_MODULES = ['digikala.spiders']
NEWSPIDER_MODULE = 'digikala.spiders'
ROBOTSTXT_OBEY = True

DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES={
    'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.useragent.UserAgentMiddleware': None,
    'digikala.middlewares.UserAgentRotatorMiddleware':400
}
AUTOTHROTTLE_START_DELAY = 60
AUTOTHROTTLE_MAX_DELAY = 120
AUTOTHROTTLE_TARGET_CONCURRENCY = 1.0
HTTPCACHE_ENABLED = True
```

I didn't find the same question. Why is it working like this? I really appreciate any help here.

Thank you!!

Comment: From your logs: `2020-09-01 13:37:29 [scrapy.extensions.httpcache] DEBUG: Using filesystem cache storage in C:\Users\shima\projects\digikala\.scrapy\httpcache`. Try setting `HTTPCACHE_ENABLED` to `False`.

Comment: Aha thank you! I fixed that @Gallaecio, this is th only degug line left. What is it about? 2020-09-01 16:04:50 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.digikala.com/search/category-book/?type[0]=4844&promotion_types[0]=promotion&pageno=1&last_filter=promotion_types&last_value=promotion&sortby=4> (referer: None)

Comment: Do you no longer get a line about using the cache? If so, can you update your question accordingly? You should consider taking the change to remove the code from your question and replace it with a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\shima\anaconda3\envs\virtual_workspace\lib\site-packages\scrapy\utils\defer.py", line 102, in iter_errback
    yield next(it)
  File "C:\Users\shima\anaconda3\envs\virtual_workspace\lib\site-packages\scrapy\spidermiddlewares\offsite.py", line 29, in process_spider_output
    for x in result:
  File "C:\Users\shima\anaconda3\envs\virtual_workspace\lib\site-packages\scrapy\spidermiddlewares\referer.py", line 339, in <genexpr>
    return (_set_referer(r) for r in result or ())

Comment: File "C:\Users\shima\anaconda3\envs\virtual_workspace\lib\site-packages\scrapy\spidermiddlewares\urllength.py", line 37, in <genexpr>
    return (r for r in result or () if _filter(r))
  File "C:\Users\shima\anaconda3\envs\virtual_workspace\lib\site-packages\scrapy\spidermiddlewares\depth.py", line 58, in <genexpr>
    return (r for r in result or () if _filter(r))
  File "C:\Users\shima\projects\digikala\digikala\spiders\promotions.py", line 23, in parse

Comment: discounted_percent = int(str(product.xpath(".//div[@class='c-price__discount-oval']/span/text()").get().strip()).replace('٪', ''))
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'strip'

Comment: Please, (1) do not post tracebacks in comments, just update your question; (2) do not reuse your question for an unrelated follow-up issue.

Comment: Sure, I'll do what you say